# Longest Palindromic Sub String

Tags: java, substring, palindrome

I am trying to solve a problem from leet code. I have written a method for that. This works perfectly in local Eclipse, but when I submitted this solution at leetcode it says time limit exceeded.

Can someone suggest to me something I can alter in the code below to make it work faster? I am also able put input string in this post.

Code:

```
public String longestPalindrome(String s) {
   if(s.equals("")) return "";
   if(s.length()==1) return s;
   if(s.length()==2) {
       if(s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(1))
           return s;      
   }

   char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
   Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
   int maxP=0;String maxPalin="";

   for(int i =2;i < s.length();i++){
       if((ch[i-1]==ch[i] || ch[i-2] == ch[i]) && !set.contains(i) ){
           int loop;
           if(ch[i-1]==ch[i]){
               loop=i-1;
           }
           else{
               loop=i-2;
           }

           for(int k =i,l=loop; l>=0 && k<s.length();k++,l--){
               if(ch[k]!= ch[l]){
                   if(maxP < s.substring(l+1, k).length())
                   maxPalin=s.substring(l+1, k);
                   maxP=s.substring(l+1, k).length();
                   set.add(i);
                   i=2;
                   break;
               }
               if(l==0){
                   if(maxP < s.substring(0, k+1).length())
                       maxPalin=s.substring(0, k+1);
                       maxP=s.substring(0, k+1).length();
                       set.add(i);
                       i=2;
                       break;
               }
               if(k== s.length()-1){
                   if(maxP < s.substring(l, s.length()).length())
                   maxPalin=s.substring(l, s.length());
                   maxP=s.substring(l, s.length()).length();
                   set.add(i);
                   i=2;
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
   }

   return maxPalin;
}
```

Input:

> ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Comment: @gunr2171 i aplogise if i missed to keep format of post. This is my first post on stackoverflow. i am just looking for a way by which i can it more faster , under 1 ms.Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry about not knowing about the formatting. There are plenty of people who keep an eye on new posts to help out with formatting issues.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the characters, for all positions check if the next character is the same as the current (e.g. 'f','f') or the character after and the character before are the same (e.g. 'f','g','f').
If that is the case, loop backward and forward and compare the characters until you find two that don't match.
Compare the length of the string with the longest you've found so far, if it is longer, save it.
Go to the next character. 
You can also exit the loop if you have found a palindrom where length/2 is larger than the number of characters left.

Comment: Thanks Jonas! Yes i agree with you exit the loop logic.

Comment: i am implementing the same logic which you iterate. But we have to go back to first character every time once we find palindrome. I am keeping break point in Hashset so that we do not searching for same substring.

Comment: for e.g   - "abbadabba"  in this case we have total 3 palindrome substring 1. abba 2.badab 3. abbadabba .  So we have to go back to start loop again when we fetch palindrome.